# Overcurrent protection, limit for nominal current or stall?

Tags: motors, design, power, circuits, current

*Background: I'm currently working on a robotics design that will drill through soil.*

**I have selected a 48V motor who's nominal current is 3.17A and has a stall current of 42A. I will be driving the motor with a microcontroller and motor driver.**

However I am having some trouble with my design.

The motor driver includes over current protection circuitry, and **I need to select a resistor to set the max allowable current.**

**Would it be more optimal to use a resistor that caps the current at exactly 3.17A? Or would it be better to provide some margin, and make it 4A?**

The over current circuitry has a feature where it resets itself after every PWM cycle and checks if the current is too large again. I believe this is "current chopping" so the motor should start up. (Startup time is not necessarily important for this.)

**Extra information:**
*Here's a link to the datasheet (overcurrent info starts at the bottom of page 12)*

[DRV83x2 Three-Phase PWM Motor Driver](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8312.pdf?ts=1608005703591)

Any input would be appreciated. Thank you for reading

Comment: Maybe this is a better question for the [Electrical Engineering SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: It would be beneficial to include datasheet in the question. Use [this link](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/posts/39157/edit) to edit the question to include datasheets

Comment: My mistake I meant to link it. Here's a link to the datasheet (overcurrent info starts at the bottom of page 12 and the circuit in question can be found on page 20)

https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8312.pdf?ts=1608005703591

Comment: I will try posting on EE SE @NMech